# Otherwise working dependency property causes "Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'property')" when set via Style's Setter

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, custom-controls, setter

Hello and nice Sunday (or some other nice day)

I have made a custom control which extends Border class. It has new dependency properties that work fine both at runtime and inside designer. They react to design-time property changes without issues, update their visual state accordingly. When I create a Style as a static resource and use it on the control to style its inherited properties, it works as expected too.

But as soon as I add a Setter which sets one of the new dependency properties, I get an exception "Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'property')" right at InitializeComponent() inside the Window constructor. I have tried digging through the exception but I could not find anything that would get me closer to a solution.

A few points that should allow anyone replying to skip obvious issues :

- all properties I have added seem to cause this error, even trivial bool types
- all properties have a *const* or *readonly static* non-null default value defined prior to registration which is then used in registration call
- I have tried several ways of adding the style; with a Style inside Window.Resources and then StaticResource binding as Style value added to the Control's tag, directly at Control, among others
- XAML shows no errors or warnings, neither does code, everything builds without issues
- applying a Style with native (inherited from Border) properties works, but as soon as a single Setter inside that Style targets one of the new properties, exception occurs - removing that single setter removes the exception

I have tried to extract the smallest amount of code to demonstrate. There are no callbacks, no logic or anything - simply a bool DependencyProperty registered with a default value. Again, works as expected in other situations but causes a crash if set via Setter inside a Style

C# :

---

```
readonly static public
DependencyProperty SelectedProperty =
DependencyProperty.Register(
    "SelectedProperty",
    typeof(bool),
    typeof(HoverBorder),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false)
);

public bool Selected{
    get=>(bool)GetValue(SelectedProperty);
    set{ SetValue(SelectedProperty,value); }
}
```

---

XAML :

---

```
// Set directly, the property works fine
<local:HoverBorder Selected="False">
    <TextBlock Text="Example Text" />
</local:HoverBorder>

// Set like this also works
<local:HoverBorder>
    <local:HoverBorder.Selected>True</local:HoverBorder.Selected>
    <TextBlock Text="Example Text" />
</local:HoverBorder>

// Set via Style crashes
<local:HoverBorder>
  <TextBlock Text="Example Text" />
  <local:HoverBorder.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <Style TargetType="local:HoverBorder">

        // Inherited property works normally
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />

        // This custom property causes the exception
        // Commenting this setter out removes the exception
        <Setter Property="Selected" Value="False" />

        // For completeness, I have also tried this with same result
        <Setter Property="local:HoverBorder.Selected" Value="False" />

      </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </local:HoverBorder.Resources>
</local:HoverBorder>
```

---

I have a feeling it is something rather basic, something regular WPF users will be able to notice right away, but I could not find any solution myself. Both the exception and problem put into any arrangement of words have proven to be too broad or vague. Therefore, I am stumped.

There is the "workaround" of not using a Style at all, but that would make my XAML hideously bloated and tedious to manage. Styles exist for a reason and I would be glad to be able to use them.

Thank you for any answers!

Comment: `DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedProperty"`: should be `DependencyProperty.Register("Selected"`

Comment: Better: `DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Selected), typeof(bool), typeof(HoverBorder));`

Comment: Thank you! It finally works. If you could post it as an answer please I will mark the question as answered.

Comment: Don't use `Register("Property",..)`   instead use `Register(nameof(Property),...)`  this is just what `nameof` is meant for.

Comment: Does this have any advantages or implications other than being able to rename the property without accidentally leaving the string unchanged?

Comment: I know others mentioned it's because you got the property name wrong, but the exception can also occur if the property's owner type does not match the style's target type